# IE8 shows 500 page when it contains regex with script replace

Tags: javascript, regex, internet-explorer, replace

IE8 seems doesn't allow to replace `<script>` e.g:

```
someHtml.replace(/<script.+<\/script>/g, "")
```

and page with that script fails to load providing that information:

> The website cannot display the page  HTTP 500
>
> Most likely causes: 
>   The website is under maintenance. 
>   The website has a programming error.
>
> What you can try:
>
> Refresh the page. Go back to the previous page. < sarcasm>Use normal browser.< /sarcasm>
>
> More information
>
> This error (HTTP 500 Internal Server Error) means that the website you
>   are visiting had a **server problem** which prevented the webpage from
>   displaying.

500 (!!) error when it clearly not server error (but wait, that's IE nothing to wonder)

However when I change `script` to `div` like so:

```
someHtml.replace(/<div.+<\/div>/g, "")
```

It works.

So I have that feeling that it is some IE bug so it tried to read `<script` as a start of script element and it fails (managed to find out that 500 error displayed even when there is not escaped slash `/` e.g. `/<div.+</div>/g` )

Or maybe there is some setting in IE that prevents to do things like that for some security means.

Can someone confirm that it is a bug or some setting needed or even something else?

Comment: 500 errors are server errors. There are plenty of times to slam your  desk and lament Internet Explorer - this is not one of them. Use developer tools to inspect every request going out to the server, to see how the parameters to any of them might be changing in unexpected ways, and thus causing the request to fail.

Comment: You probably won't be able to find the issue with those IE-sucks glasses on!